# nodejs function not setting variable, net-ping

Tags: node.js, function, callback, node-modules

Trying to set a variable based on the result of running session.pingHost, the pingHost function works but it's not setting my variable like I expect.

```
import ping from 'net-ping';

let TEMPIP = '8.8.8.8';
let session = ping.createSession();
let ipset = false;

session.pingHost(TEMPIP, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Offline');
    ipset = false;
  } else {
    console.log('Alive');
    ipset = true;
  }
});

console.log(ipset);
```

result:

```
false
"Alive"
```

Expected result:

```
"Alive"
true
```

Adding code for how I got it to work

```
function pingfunction(TEMPIP) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    session.pingHost(TEMPIP, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Offline');
        reject(false);
      } else {
        console.log('Alive');
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  });
}
pingfunction(TEMPIP)
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `=` instead of `==`.
`==` is for comparison whereas `=` is for assigning value to a variable.

Comment: I'm still getting the same results after changing to "="

Answer (score 0):

The reason `ipset` is set to false is because the call to console.log is called before the callback for `session.pingHost`. You need to move the call to console.log inside the callback function for `session.pingHost' like this:

```
import ping from 'net-ping';

let TEMPIP = '8.8.8.8';
let session = ping.createSession();
let ipset = false;

session.pingHost(TEMPIP, function(error) {
  console.log("CALLED")

  if (error) {
    console.log('Offline');
    ipset = false;
  } else {
    console.log('Alive');
    ipset = true;
  }
  console.log(ipset);
});
```